# cancel a set of axios get request when components are changed, in react

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.state.card_list.map(card => this.setData(card))
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.selectedDivision !== this.props.selectedDivision
            || prevProps.selectedDistrict !== this.props.selectedDistrict) {
            this.state.card_list.map(card => this.setData(card))
        }
    }

    setData(card) {

        this.setState({
            [card.state]: null
        })

        let api = card.api
            + `?sort=${card.sort}`
            + `${this.props.selectedDivision ? `&division=${this.props.selectedDivision}` : ''}`
            + `${this.props.selectedDistrict ? `&district=${this.props.selectedDistrict}` : ''}`

        axios.get(api)
            .then(res => this.setState({
                [card.state]: res.data.results.sort((a, b) => b[card.display_data_key] - a[card.display_data_key])
            }))
            .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
```

here is my code, in this componentDidMount I have mapped over an array named card_list. For each element of card_list, I call a function setData which makes an axios GET request to set data for that card. in componentDidUpdate I have mapped again over the same array. Now I want to cancel all previous axios requests when the if-condition is true in the componentDidUpdate.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: @jadz this is for a single call, but here I am looping over an array and each time calling an API, all those APIs should be canceled when  props are updated